# Swift Ios Parse SearchBar Complication

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I was recently following a tutorial which shows an early version of **Swift** being used to create a table of users from **Parse** with a search function. The following code has allowed me to display all users in a table as I would like, but does not update the table once search text has been put in the search bar. (There are two user arrays because I am relatively new to programming and was following two different tutorials to help make this table). Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
var userArray: [String] = []
var userList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! = UISearchBar()


func loadUsers(name:String){
    var findUsers:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    if !name.isEmpty {
        findUsers.whereKey("name", containsString: name)
    }
    findUsers.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            self.userList = NSMutableArray(array: objects)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    loadUsers(searchText)
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    loadUsers("")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadUsers("")
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    var users = query.findObjects()

    for user in users {
        userArray.append(user["name"] as String)
        println(userArray)
    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return userArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

     if userArray.count >= 1 {
       cell.textLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row]
     }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a new array which holds the data which hold's the results in the searchBar.

Besides, it's better to create a bool variable to handle what's the data showing in the screen (true for search results, false for loadUsers).

This article can help you: http://shrikar.com/blog/2015/02/16/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate

Comment: Thank you I was able to follow this tutorial and solve my problem!